# graphql variable types

Tags: go, graphql

I use https://github.com/shurcooL/graphql for graphql queries and I need to make the following mutation:

```
mutation createPromotion($input: CreatePromotionInput) {
  createPromotion(input: $input)
}
```

with the following graphql variables:

```
{
 "input": {
    "channel": "my_channel",
    "offerType": "my_offer_type",
   }
}
```

In my code it looks like this:

```
type CreatePromotion struct {
    CreatePromotion graphql.String
}

func (g *Gate) CreatePromotion(ctx context.Context) (*CreatePromotion, error) {
var mutation struct {
    CreatePromotion CreatePromotion `graphql:"createPromotion(input: {channel: $channel, 
  offerType: $offerType})"`
}

variables := map[string]interface{}{
    "channel":    graphql.String("my_channel"),
    "offerType":  graphql.String("my_offer_type"),//error is here
}
err := g.graphqlClient.Mutate(ctx, &mutation, variables)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
 }
 return &mutation.CreatePromotion, nil
}
```

But when I execute my query I get the following error: `Variable "$offerType" of type "String!" used in position expecting type "OfferType!"`. Unfortunately I neither have idea what type `OfferType!` is, nor how am I expected to make it.

Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: The error is pretty direct: you’re passing a string as a value for the `offerType` parameter, but it expects an `OfferType`. You’ll need to look at the schema and figure out how to create one of those